# Uso de populate() con Mongoose referenciando a índices hijos de un document

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy intentando regresar el nombre y el apellido del usuario que creó un document, así como el que lo modificó por última vez. Estoy usando `populate()` para hacer el JOIN entre las dos colecciones pero no me ha resultado.

Este es el modelo de **areas**

```
var mongo     = require('mongoose'),
    validator = require('mongoose-unique-validator'),
    Schema    = mongo.Schema


var model = new Schema({
    NAME:       { type: String, required: true, unique: true, max: 50, min: 3 },
    STATUS:     { type: String, default: 'active' },
    ADDED_BY:   { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
    ADDED_DATE: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    MODIFY_BACKLOG :[{
        USER:     { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'users' },
        DATE:     { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        CURRENT:  { type: String },
        MODIFIED: { type: String }
    }]


}, {collection :'areas'})

model.plugin( validator, { message: 'The {PATH} is not valid or duplicated' } )
module.exports = mongo.model('Area', model )
```

Como podrán darse cuenta los índices `ADDED_BY` y `MODIFY_BACKLOG.USER` están haciendo referencia a la colección `users`.

Este es el modelo de los **users**

```
var mongo     = require('mongoose'),
    validator = require('mongoose-unique-validator'),
    Schema = mongo.Schema

var userSchema = new Schema({
    PERSONAL_DATA: {
        NAME:            { type: String, required: [ true, 'The name is necessary' ], max: 50 },
        LAST_NAME:       { type: String, required: [ true, 'the lastname is necessary' ], max: 100 },
        PHOTO:           { type: String, max: 100 },
        BIRTHDAY:        { type: Date },
        MARITIAL_STATUS: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'maritial_statuses' },
        GENDER:          { type: String, max: 1 },
        EMAIL:           { type: String, required: true  },
    },
    COMPANY_DATA: {
        JOB:      { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'jobs' },
        AREA:     { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'areas' },
        ROLE:     { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'roles' },
        BOSS:     { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
    }
}, { collection: 'users' } )

model.plugin( validator, { message: 'The {PATH} is not valid or duplicated' } )

module.exports = mongo.model('User', userSchema )
```

Como la información es muy robusta en este modelo decidí separarlo en `PERSONAL_DATA, COMPANY_DATA` y hay otros dos índices `PAYMENT_DATA, ENGINE_DATA` cada uno de estos guarda índices que respectan al nombre del padre, pero esos no me interesan porque no tienen algo que ver con la pregunta y es un modelo de aprox. 300 líneas.

Dentro de `COMPANY_DATA.AREA` es donde se incluye el área a donde el usuario pertenece, no creo que sea de relevancia para este problema, pero por si acaso.

Esta es la **ruta** que consume el modelo de areas

```
var express = require('express'),
    Areas   = require('../../models/catalogs/areas'),
    app     = express()

app.get('/:from', (req, res) => {

    var from = parseInt( req.params.from )
    var populate = { 
        path: 'users', 
        select: 'NAME LAST_NAME'
    }
    Areas.find()
        .sort('NAME').populate( populate )
        .limit(10).skip(from)
        .exec((error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    success: false,
                    error
                })
            }

            Areas.count({}, ( err, total ) => {
                res.status(200).json({
                    success: true,
                    data,
                    total
                })
            })
            
        })
})

module.exports = app
```

Al método `populate()` le estoy pasando una variable con el mismo nombre, donde estoy haciendo la referencia a la colección y qué datos necesito del usuario.
Aquí es donde estoy atorado porque no me está trayendo la información del usuario, sólo me trae la información del área y aquí tengo tres preguntas

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me respete el JOIN de las colecciones?

¿Cómo puedo decirle que los índices que necesito no están explicitamente al primer nivel del document, sino dentro de PERSONAL_DATA?
Intenté con

```
var populate = { 
        path: 'users', 
        select: 'PERSONAL_DATA.NAME PERSONAL_DATA.LAST_NAME'
    }
```

Pero sigue igual, por último

El índice `MODIFY_BACKLOG` en el modelo de áreas tiene dentro también el ObjectId del usuario que hizo la modificación, ¿cómo puedo decir que también a ese índice haga el JOIN a usuarios?

Dejo un ejemplo de la respuesta

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [{
        "STATUS": "active",
        "_id": "5c547f4adadf433914f72c8c",
        "NAME": "Contabilidad y Finanzas",
        "ADDED_BY": "5c4f562deec6f4defeea759b",
        "ADDED_DATE": "2019-02-01T17:18:02.680Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "MODIFY_BACKLOG": []
    }, {
        "STATUS": "active",
        "_id": "5c645f476491cf093c51c38e",
        "NAME": "Recursos Humanos",
        "ADDED_BY": "5c4f562deec6f4defeea759b",
        "ADDED_DATE": "2019-02-13T18:17:43.036Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "MODIFY_BACKLOG": [{
            "DATE": "2019-02-13T19:43:18.273Z",
            "_id": "5c6473561370462754939107",
            "USER": "5c4f562deec6f4defeea759b",
            "CURRENT": "active",
            "MODIFIED": "{\"STATUS\":\"inactive\"}"
        }, {
            "DATE": "2019-02-13T19:43:24.213Z",
            "_id": "5c64735c1370462754939108",
            "USER": "5c4f562deec6f4defeea759b",
            "CURRENT": "inactive",
            "MODIFIED": "{\"STATUS\":\"active\"}"
        }]
    }],
    "total": 5
}
```

Comment: acepta respuesta con agregados ?

Comment: Me gustaría que fuera natural con `populate()` puesto que debería hacerlo simple, postea tu respuesta y si no hay nadie que lo pueda hacer con dicha función exploramos con `aggregate()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores que iré detallando poco a poco

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea consultar una Base de Datos Mongo, desde una aplicación Express, usando Mongoose como ODM.

El documento que se consulta pertenece a la colección `areas` y tiene un campo que referencia al `ObjectId` de otro documento. A saber, el campo `ADDED_BY`  contiene una referencia al campo `_id` de un documento en la colección `users`.

La consulta que se realiza utiliza el método `populate()` (de Mongoose) para indicarle al motor de Mongo, que se desea devolver los campos establecidos (del documento de la colección `users`) en el campo que contiene la referencia.

Se usa un objeto llamado `populate` que se le pasa como argumento al método `populate()`

**SOLUCIÓN**

Aqui iré indicando los errores que cometes y además algunas sugerencias:

El primer error que veo en tu código se encuentra en la definición del modelo `User`:

```
model.plugin( validator, { message: 'The {PATH} is not valid or duplicated' });
```

Esta línea debería ser:

```
userSchema.plugin( validator, { message: 'The {PATH} is not valid or duplicated'});
```

Imagino que es un error de 'copiar y pegar'

Luego, una sugerencia que puedo hacerte es cómo defines tu referencia:

```
ADDED_BY:   { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
```

Yo, normalmente uso un nombre en singular, que además coincide con el modelo al que hago referencia, no con el nombre de la colección. Como digo esta es solo una sugerencia:

```
ADDED_BY:   { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
```

Por último, la forma en que usas el método `populate()` es la que está causando tu problema.

En la [documentación oficial de Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), indica lo siguiente: (traducción propia)

> 'Population' es el proceso de reemplazo automático de las rutas especificadas en el documento con uno o  varios documentos de otra colección o colecciones.

Visto esto, el problema es que tu no especificas la ruta a la que quieres reemplazarle la data correctamente. Me parece que asumes erróneamente que `ref` es el nombre que debes usar en la ruta que quieres reemplazar.

Así tu objeto `populate` debería ser de la siguiente forma:

```
const populate = {path: 'ADDED_BY', select: 'PERSONAL_DATA.NAME PERSONAL_DATA.LASTNAME'}
```

Puedes observar que uso `PERSONAL_DATA.NAME` y `PERSONAL_DATA.LAST_NAME` como parámetros del `select`.

En cuanto al `array` que almacena el log de modificaciones. La solución es la misma, pero con una pequeña diferencia. Vamos a crear un objeto llamado `populateLog` de la sigueinte manera:

```
const populateLog = {path: 'MODIFY_BACKLOG.USER', select: 'PERSONAL_DATA.NAME PERSONAL_DATA.LAST_NAME'}
```

Como puedes observar, el `path` del objeto es `MODIFY_BACKLOG.USER`, y es que precisamente, el campo `USER` de `MODIFY_BACKLOG` es el que deseamos llenar con los datos adicionales.

Mongoose llenará cada elemento del `array` con los datos que le estamos requiriendo.

Ahora podemos llamar el método en nuestra cadena de métodos:

```
Areas.find()
    .sort('NAME')
    .populate(populate)
    .populate(populateLog)
    .limit(10).skip(from)
    .exec(...);
```

Como puedes ver llamo 2 veces el método `populate()` y a cada uno le paso el objeto correspondiente.

Haciendo estos pequeños cambios tu código debe funcionar.

Un ejemplo de la respuesta usando `GET` con Postman a mi propia implementación es la siguiente:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "areas": [
        {
            "STATUS": "inactive",
            "_id": "5c67fcd380215f1da71f56ab",
            "NAME": "Quinta area",
            "ADDED_BY": {
                "PERSONAL_DATA": {
                    "NAME": "Andres",
                    "LASTNAME": "Contreras"
                },
                "_id": "5c67ef0b6b2d6f14cddd0766"
            },
            "ADDED_DATE": "2019-02-16T12:06:43.331Z",
            "MODIFY_BACKLOG": [
                {
                    "DATE": "2019-02-16T12:10:47.168Z",
                    "_id": "5c67fdc7cdced81e2b29dd8e",
                    "USER": {
                        "PERSONAL_DATA": {
                            "NAME": "Mauricio",
                            "LASTNAME": "Contreras"
                        },
                        "_id": "5c67eecb6b2d6f14cddd0764"
                    },
                    "CURRENT": "active",
                    "MODIFIED": "modified"
                },
                {
                    "DATE": "2019-02-16T14:25:08.326Z",
                    "_id": "5c681d44a3147338af6d52cd",
                    "USER": {
                        "PERSONAL_DATA": {
                            "NAME": "Ernesto",
                            "LASTNAME": "Contreras"
                        },
                        "_id": "5c680f0897528d2d187538af"
                    },
                    "CURRENT": "active",
                    "MODIFIED": "modified"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 2
        }
     ],
    "total": 7
}
```

Como puedes ver, el documento devuelto contiene la información que hemos llenado usando el método `populate()`, tanto para el campo `ADDED_BY` como para el campo `MODIFY_BACKLOG`, siendo que este último es un `array`, cada elemento del `array` contiene la información correcta.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Cuando creé el model de user, me intriga, por que yo estaba seguro que en el parámetro `ref` iba la colección pero de MongoDB! no el modelo de Mongoose. Probaré tu propuesta, me hace mucho sentido lo que pusiste, gracias.

Comment: Si deseas que suba a Github lo que tengo hecho a modo de prueba me avisas, lo único que requiere es que tengas instalado un servidor local de MongoDB

Comment: Al fin subí mi implementación a [Github](https://github.com/virtualkur2/mongoose_examples), aunque no he comentado el código todavía. Puedes realizar pruebas de lo que tengo allí, si lees el README verás como usar el ejemplo. Cualquier duda comentas. Saludos

Comment: Ya tuve la oportunidad de probarlo y quedó fenomenal. Gracias sensei.