# Populate de un array de IDs anidada en mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo el modelos de los usuarios y el modelos de los post.
En el modelo de los post, cuando un usuario hace like a un post, hago referencia a la id de ese usuario.

En el modelo de los user hago lo mismo, cuando el user da like a un post, añado la id del post al que le ha dado like.

Cuando se cargan los posts, necesito obtener la data de los usuarios que han dado like a ese post y he hecho lo siguiente:

Modelo user:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({

name: {
    type: String,
    required: [ true, 'El nombre es necesario' ]
},
avatar: {
    type: String,
    default: `av-1.png`
},
email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [ true, 'El email es necesario' ]
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: [ true, 'La contraseña es necesaria' ]
},
likes: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,//String
     ref: 'Post'
}]});
```

Modelo post:

```
const postSchema = new Schema({

 created: {
    type: Date
},
message: {
    type: String
},
imgs: [{
    type: String
}],
coords: {
    type: String
},
user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: [ true, 'Debe existir una relación con un usuario' ]
},
info: {
    likes: {
        number: {
            type: Number
        },
        usersId: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }]
    }
}    });
```

Obtención de los post con los usuarios que han dado like populados:

```
const posts = await Post.find()
                        .sort({_id: -1})                 // Orden descendente
                        .skip( skip )
                        .limit(10)                       // Maximo 10 por petición
                        .populate('user', '-password')
                        .populate( { 
                            path: 'metrics',
                            populate: {
                                path: 'likes',
                                populate: {
                                    path: 'userId',
                                  } 
                              } 

                         } )  // Obtener datos user -pass
                        .exec(); 

res.json({
    ok: true,
    page,
    posts
});
```

Error:
(node:8216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ usersId: [] }" at path "_id" for model "Post"

¿Como puedo hacer para obtener la data de todos los usuarios que hay en el array userId?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Uso de populate() con Mongoose referenciando a indices hijos de un document](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/237695/uso-de-populate-con-mongoose-referenciando-a-indices-hijos-de-un-document)

Answer (score 1):

Ya está, al final lo he solucionado escribiendo bien la referencia (ponía userId y lo tenína referenciado en plural, usersId) y ahorrando alguna linea de código.

```
const posts = await Post.find()
                        .sort({_id: -1})                 
                        .skip( skip )
                        .limit(10)                       
                        .populate('user', '-password')   
                        .populate('metrics.likes.usersId')
                        .exec();
```