# ¿Como usar el populate en Mongoose con array de 2 dimensiones?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy intentando consultar un documento que contiene un array de objetos que internamente tiene array de ids. Estoy intentando usar `populate()` para hacer la subconsultar y no logro obtener el resultado.

Este es mi modelo de los roles:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose"

export interface Interface extends Document {
    name: String;
    status: Boolean;
    modules: Array;
    created_at: Date;
    updated_at: Date;
}

const schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario'],
    },
    modules: [{
        module_id:   { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Module' },
        function_id: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Function",
        }],
    }],
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    },
    created :[{
        by: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User' },
        at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    }],
    modify_log :[{
        by: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User' },
        at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        old:  { type: String },
        new:  { type: String },
    }],
})

export default mongoose.model("Role", schema)
```

*modules* es un array de objetos, estos objetos tienen id y un array de ids.

El modelo de *Module* es el sig:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose"

export interface Interface extends Document {
    parent_id: Number;
    icon: String;
    link: String;
    title: String;
    status: Boolean;
    created_at: Date;
    updated_at: Date;
}

const schema = new Schema({
    parent_id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    icon: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    link: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: false,
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    },
    created :[{
        by: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User' },
        at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    }],
    modify_log :[{
        by: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User' },
        at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        new:  { type: String },
        old:  { type: String },
    }],
})

export default mongoose.model("Module",schema)
```

Asi es como lo estoy intentando llamar con mongoose:

```
const populate = {path: 'modules.module_id', select: 'module.link module.title'}

const result = await Role.findById(id).populate(populate)
```

Obtengo este resultado:

```
{
  status: true,
  _id: 5f9a02d0da62727cbd41d1d5,
  name: 'Investor Creative Executive',
  modules: [
    {
      function_id: [ 5f99e4b4b66dd75631eb62fe, 5f99e599b0743b57e1e2ccca ],
      _id: 5f99e622eaad9e5ba19c5d33
    },
    {
      function_id: [ 5f99e4b4b66dd75631eb62fe ],
      _id: 5f99e62788ffee5be0a9bb42
    },
    {
      function_id: [
        5f99e4b4b66dd75631eb62fe,
        5f99e599b0743b57e1e2ccca,
        5f99e5ade81b6a584313e3d4
      ],
      _id: 5f99e62d7e4ea25c1250d4b8
    }
  ],
  created: [],
  modify_log: [],
  __v: 0
}
```

En la DB tengo registrados los datos de la sig forma:

[image]

Intenté guiarme de [**esta pregunta en esOS**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/237695/uso-de-populate-con-mongoose-referenciando-a-indices-hijos-de-un-document) y no pude hacer que funcionara para mi.

**Actualización 1:**

Controlador completo, para mostrar cómo importo el modelo.

```
import {Request, Response} from 'express'
import Role from '../models/Role'

class RoleController {
    async getOne (req : Request, res : Response){

        let errors = []
        let result = null

        const params = req.params;
        const id = (params?.id) ? ((params.id=='null')?null:params.id):null;
        if(!id){
            errors.push('Debe indicar un ID')
        }
        if (errors.length != 0) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                msg: 'Error',
                errors,
            })
        }

        const populate = {path: 'modules.module_id', select: 'link title'}

        try {
            result = await Role.findById(id).populate(populate)
            console.log('result',result)
            console.log('modules',result?.modules)
        } catch (err) {
            errors.push('Error al consultar un usuario')
        }
        if (errors.length != 0) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                msg: 'Error',
                errors,
            })
        }
        return res.status(200).json(result)
    }
}

const controller = new RoleController();

export default controller;
```

Comment: El error es de tipeo, o al menos así lo veo yo, debes escribir los campos a devolver en el método `populate` así: `select: 'link title'` ya que en el documento referenciado no existe `module.link` ni `module.title`, sólo existe `link` y `title` (entre otros). Prueba eso y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras me falla igual bro :/

Comment: Trataré de responder pronto, ya mi zona horaria no me lo permite, pero en cuanto pueda te doy una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras no te preocupes bro, cuando puedas. Mil gracias.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿cómo estás importando tus modelos? Me parece que Mongoose no está resolviendo la referencia debido a que tal vez tu modelo `Role` es instanciado antes que tu modelo `Module`. ¿Puedes aclarar esto?

Comment: @MauricioContreras bro lo agregué a la pregunta.

Comment: Por más que intento reproducir tu problema, no lo consigo. En la imagen que muestras, no se ve que en tu objeto modules tengas un valor llamado `module_id`, ¿Esos son los datos que hay almacenados en DB? Si es así, jamás hará un `populate` sobre un campo que no exista en el documento. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

yobany_vicentes:
Yo tenía el mismo problema y lo reslví así:
Mi problema era que necesitaba el nombre de un doctor, y ese doctor estaba ligado a un espacio disponible, y asu vez este espacio disponible estaba ligado a una cita médica. Que en resumen se vería así:

appointment.availability.user.name

```
.populate([  
    {
       path: 'availability', select: 'user day month year time topic'
    }
         ]);
```

Pero el programa me arrojaba error al llamar el nombre así: appointment.availability.user.name, entonces le quitaba el name, y lo dejaba hasta user: appointment.availability.user, pero entonces visualmente me aparecía era el _id del user, así que para solucionarlo y poder acceder al nombre mediante appointment.availability.user.name sin que me apareciera el error, reformulé el populate así:

```
.populate([
      {
        path: 'availability', populate: { path: 'user' }, select: 'name day month year time topic'
      }
        ]);
```

Lo anterior porque tenía más variables, pero sólo a nivel del problema que tenía, sería cambiar:

```
.populate([  
    {
       path: 'availability', select: 'user.name'
    }
         ]);
```

por:

```
populate([
      {
        path: 'availability', populate: { path: 'user' }, select: 'name'
      }
        ]);
```