# populate dentro de un array mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

No sabria como utilizar populate dentro de un array de objetos que tiene mi modelo.

Modelo

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const mongooseDelete = require('mongoose-delete');

const damageSchema = Schema(
    {
        car: {
            interno: Number,
            vin: {
                type: String,
                uppercase: true
            },
            order: {
                type: String,
                uppercase: true
            },
            ope: {
                numOp: Number,
                typeOp: {
                    type: Schema.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'TypeOp'
                }
            }
        },
        damage: {
            typeDamage: {
                type: Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'TypeDamage'
            },
            repair: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            history: [
                {
                    details: String,
                    date: {
                        type: Date,
                        default: Date.now
                    }
                }
            ],
            img: [
                {
                    img: String,
                    details: String
                }
            ],
            damages:[
                {
                    severityCode: {
                        type: Schema.ObjectId,
                        ref: 'SeverityCode'
                    },
                    damageCode: {
                        type: Schema.ObjectId,
                        ref: 'DamageCode'
                    },
                    damageDetails: {
                        type: Schema.ObjectId,
                        ref: 'DamageDetail'
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        versionKey: false
    }
)

damageSchema.plugin(mongooseDelete, { overrideMethods: 'all' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Damage', damageSchema);
```

El populate tendria que ser en damage.damages[]

Ya estuve buscando y no encontre casos parecidos, si un array de objetos, pero no un populate dentro del objeto del array

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Uso de populate() con Mongoose referenciando a índices hijos de un document](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/237695/uso-de-populate-con-mongoose-referenciando-a-%c3%adndices-hijos-de-un-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue bajar un nivel mas en el objeto, adjunto código

```
const getItem = async (req, res) => {

    const data = await damageModel
        .findOne({ "_id": req.params.id })
        .populate({
            path: "car.ope.typeOp",
            model: "TypeOp"
        })
        .populate({
            path: "damage.typeDamage",
            model: "TypeDamage"
        })
        .populate({
            path: "damage.damages.severityCode",
            model: "SeverityCode"
        })
        .populate({
            path: "damage.damages.damageCode",
            model: "DamageCode"
        })
        .populate({
            path: "damage.damages.damageDetails",
            model: "DamageDetail"
        })

    return res.status(200)
        .json({
            status: 'success',
            data
        });
}
```